# Mi modelo Keras predice todos los resultados con el mismo orden de magnitud

Tags: python, tensorflow, redes-neuronales, keras, inteligencia-artificial

He implementado un modelo de regresión con keras para predecir valores comprendidos entre e-06 y e-16. Como resultado obtengo todas las predicciones en torno a e-07.

```
def _base_model():

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(20, kernel_regularizer='l2', input_dim=12, activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(20, kernel_regularizer='l2', activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(1, kernel_regularizer='l2', activation='sigmoid'))
optimizer = Adam(lr=0.0004)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=optimizer)    

return model

mms_x = MinMaxScaler()
mms_y = MinMaxScaler()

x_n = mms_x.fit_transform(x)
y_n = mms_y.fit_transform(np.reshape(y, (-1, 1)))
x_test_n = mms_x.transform(x_test)
y_test_n = mms_y.transform(np.reshape(y_test, (-1, 1)))

estimator = KerasRegressor(build_fn=_base_model, batch_size=int(0.5 * x_n.shape[0]), epochs=500, verbose=0)
estimator.fit(x_n, y_n)

prediction = estimator.predict(x_test_n)
y_prediction = mms_y.inverse_transform(np.reshape(prediction, (-1, 1)))
```

A continuación, adjunto una muestra de los resultados de los datos usados para testear. Dónde *y_test* son los valores reales, *y_test_n* son los valores reales normalizados, *x_test* son los valores de entrada, *x_test_n* son los valores de entrada normalizados, *prediction* son los valores predichos y *y_prediction* son los valores predichos por la red neuronal desnormalizados.

```
x_test =array([[ 9.13032945e-01,  4.48543615e-01,  1.21471379e-01, 4.59691231e-01, -7.04107682e-03,  5.73655959e-01, 1.00000000e+01,  1.68139129e+02,  1.69052954e+00, 2.35857913e+03,  1.89170054e-01,  3.43569995e+05],
   [ 7.37279859e-01, -5.96543058e-01,  6.84791770e-02, 4.41210980e-01, -4.92003347e-01,  4.64064726e-01, 1.20000000e+01,  1.68480774e+02,  1.15835211e+00, 2.38161126e+03,  2.34036465e-01,  3.72224318e+05],
   [-2.59021404e-01,  3.71261309e-01, -2.16156287e-01, 5.43236826e-01, -5.49188926e-01,  4.30326427e-01, 1.10000000e+01,  1.60467909e+02,  2.15319911e+00, 2.25034828e+03,  1.02604495e-01,  3.50939780e+05],
   [-1.48442354e-01, -2.42855924e-01,  1.45341381e+00, 1.61903722e-01, -4.49263401e-01, -4.97033700e-02, 1.00000000e+01,  1.63156903e+02,  1.04367354e+00, 2.29026170e+03,  3.45005454e-03,  3.67569205e+05],
   [ 3.10436067e-01,  6.74157574e-01, -6.90708038e-01,  4.13188254e-01, -2.11920676e-01, -2.27031896e-02, 9.00000000e+00,  1.58041848e+02,  2.95811262e+00, 2.34772870e+03,  2.06509396e-03,  3.91810272e+05]])

x_test_n = array([[ 0.94321214,  0.64423385,  0.36997323,  0.4599793,  0.93059294, 0.71810821,  0.6       ,  0.87906269,  0.3443942 ,  0.94814897, 0.75761119,  0.03479036],
   [ 0.82539998,  0.17762936,  0.35188916,  0.4412975 ,  0.60524863, 0.64474332,  1.        ,  0.90215806,  0.07711882,  0.97723242,  0.94246606,  0.3247232 ],
   [ 0.15755166,  0.60972927,  0.25475472,  0.54443608,  0.56688481, 0.62215752,  0.8       ,  0.36048499,  0.57676067,  0.81148219,  0.40095094,  0.10936   ],
   [ 0.23167586,  0.33554163,  0.82451071,  0.158944  ,  0.63392137,  0.3008058 ,  0.6       ,  0.54226209,  0.01952382,  0.86188222,-0.00757698,  0.27762139]
   [ 0.53927477,  0.74496471,  0.09280962,  0.41296914,  0.79314635, 0.31888084,  0.4       ,  0.19648227,  0.98101225,  0.93444776, -0.01328318,  0.52289961]])

y_test = array([[2.27514056e-08],
   [2.91341941e-14],
   [4.97753140e-14],
   [5.77807211e-12],
   [1.77576774e-14]])

y_test_n = array([[3.35294144e-03],
   [4.29323122e-09],
   [7.33517368e-09],
   [8.51531092e-07],
   [2.61664056e-09]])

prediction = array([[0.13964666],
   [0.09875984],
   [0.0484926 ],
   [0.14387827],
   [0.04030625]])

y_prediction = array([[9.4757331e-07],
   [6.7013553e-07],
   [3.2904686e-07],
   [9.7628686e-07],
   [2.7349833e-07]])
```

Se utilizan 85 datos para entrenar la red neuronal.

Comment: Por favor, puedes dar una definición mayor de todo el problema y lo que estás intentado solucionar, para tener un contexto.  Los tipos de datos que estás usando, etc. Además incluye más código, ya que faltan muchas cosas para poder ayudarte.

Comment: @RubialesAlberto he añadido parte de los datos usados para testear y algo más del código. El problema, como se puede ver en los resultados de la predicción, es que todos los valores que predice la red son del orden de e-07 o e-06 y no deberían. Si necesitas algo más dímelo y lo añado. Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Lo mejor es que adjuntases todo el código, incluyendo los resultados predichos y las transformaciones de los datos, pero de entrada 85 datos son extremadamente pocos para cualquier modelo, y mucho más para una red neuronal, lo primero que te recomiendo es que consigas más datos. Por otro lado no entiendo por qué dices que no debería predecir resultados e-07, entiendo que digas que la red neuronal predice mal, pero no "que no debería"

Comment: @RubialesAlberto me refería a que predice mal, no me he expresado adecuadamente.

Comment: Gracias por toda la información agregada da gusto resolver problemas así!

Comment: Gracias a ti por tu respuesta y por ayudarme. La tendré en cuenta. @RubialesAlberto

Comment: De nada siempre es un gusto ayudar :) Si te ha servido mis respuesta, la mejor forma de dar las gracias en StackOverflow es aceptando la respuesta en el tick  "aceptar respuesta",  y ¿Por qué no? ¡Darle también un voto positivo! Esto no solo me recomenpensara a mí por la ayuda, si no que hará que la pregunta perdure en el tiempo y le pueda ser de ayuda a personas con el mismo problema que tú en el futuro! Te recomiendo leer [Vota pronto, vota con frecuencia](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2209/vota-pronto-vota-con-frecuencia)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De los problemas que hay encuentro dos, que afectan notablemente al funcionamiento de tu red neuronal:

### 1. Pocos datos

Las redes neuronales necesitan una **gran cantidad de datos** (depende del problema) hay en casos en los que con algo más de mil es suficiente (pocos), si la variable dependiente es facilmente predecible, pero siempre cuanto más datos mejor, de hecho la mayoría de redes neuronales en la vida real tienen **millones de datos**.

A mayor cantidad de datos, más fácil le será a la red neuronal **generalizar** y **capturar la varianza** de tus datos adecuadamente, asignando los pesos a las neuronas y las activaciones correspondientes según el tipo de dato.

### 2.No estandarizar la variable dependiente

En este caso estás estandarizando la variable dependiente (lo que quieres predecir), lo cual no tiene sentido, la razón de estandarizar las variables independientes (las predictoras) es que **la diferencia de magnitudes entre distintas variables, no lleve a la red neuronal a ponderar unas variables más importantes que otras por el simple hecho de tener magnitudes numéricas mayores**, ya que esto provoca que la red neuronal *capture mal* la varianza de tus datos.

En este caso la variable dependiente, no está prediciendo nada, **está siendo predicha por el resto de variables**, por lo que no debes estandarizarla.